# How select data from TABLE 2 join with table 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How i can to select the user that login for to show name in php, the table 1 is for the main users, and the table 2 is extra users, relationated  with main user by ID and ID_ppl

I need show in php the user name that login. but only it show me the main user, Although I login with extra user, And it must show tha name extra user.

For example, i Login with **Juana**, and in php show me **Andres**, the main user; when it must show me Juana name

Table 1 Main users

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | nivel | estado | 
----------------------------------------------------
1  | Andres    | *****    | e12A1 | 1     | on     |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2 extra users

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | id_ppl | nivel | estado |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Juana     | *****    |       | 1      | 2     | on     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Martin    | *****    |       | 1      | 2     | off    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Php query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT T1.id, T1.usuario, T1.token, T1.nivel, T1.estado FROM escolar AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario, $password); 
     $stmt->execute(); 
     $stmt->store_result(); 
     if($stmt->num_rows > 0){ 
     $stmt->bind_result($id, $usuario, $token, $nivel, $estado);
     $stmt->fetch();

    $user = array(
     'id' => $id,
     'usuario' => $usuario,
     'token' => $token,
     'nivel' => $nivel,
     'estado' => $estado
     );
```

Comment: I could not understand the relationship between these tables. Both of them are having same fields. It is a **one to many** relationship of main-users towards extra-users that doesn't make sense though.

Comment: The key is TOKEN, the token is generated automatic when a user login, and a main user can have 2 extra users assosiated a this account, and every extra user must have a specific token

Comment: Ok.. Try using this:

`SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM escolar AS T1  JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl WHERE T1.usuario = $username OR T2.usuario = $username`

where $username is the field user logs in with

Answer (score 2):

You're only selecting from T1. You need to include the users from T2.

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.usuario AS extrausers
FROM escolar AS T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl
```

Also, since there are multiple extra users in T2 per user in T1, you'll get multiple rows in your results (one row for each extra user).  You may want to account for that in your php.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out**

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.usuario, T1.usuario, T1.token, T1.nivel, T1.estado FROM escolar AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl;
```

**Your'e not selecting any column from T2**

Thank you ;)